# What does CCriticalSection do?

Tags: c++, winapi

What the diffrence between this code:

```
::EnterCriticalSection( &m_CriticalSection );
//...
::LeaveCriticalSection( &m_CriticalSection );
```

and the code:

```
static CCriticalSection cs;
cs.Lock();
//...
cs.UnLock();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference practically. `CCriticalSection` is the only *syntatic* sugar of the former. It **internally** uses `EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection!`

`EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection` are low-level win32 APIs, while `CCriticalSection` is a MFC class which wraps these functionalities. It has a member data of  type `CRITICAL_SECTION` which is used by the APIs.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5zew56b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says,

> The functionality of the
>   CCriticalSection class is provided by
>   an actual Win32 CRITICAL_SECTION
>   object.

Answer (score 9):

If you use it that way, there is no difference. The main benefit to the class is if you use it as follows:

```
static CCriticalSection cs;
{
  CSingleLock lock(cs, true);
  // do your work here
} // unlocked automatically
```

When the scope is exited the critical section will be unlocked, even if an exception was thrown or an early return was used. The technique is known as [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) and is widely known.

The MFC synchronisation classes are not that well designed. I would recommend using the boost.thread ones or the ones that will be available in the new C++ standard if you can get your hands on them.

Answer (score 2):

It encapsulates `CRITICAL_SECTION` structure and the four operations - `InitializeCriticalSection()`, `EnterCriticalSection()`, `LeaveCriticalSection()` and `DeleteCriticalSection()` into a single class making it more convenient to write code.