# MessageQueue Synchronization using Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I have a requirement for an MessageQueue which will store objects and 2 threads will act as producer and cousumer. i am planning to use `std::queue` to store objects. I am working in MFC and C++ on VC 6.0 .For synchronization between 2 threads which syncronization primitives could be used as I can't use C++ 11 on VC 6.0.

Please provide me some direction? I am planning to use `CriticalSection` and `Event`. Is there any better way to handle this?
Is `std::queue` is thread-safe?

Comment: Is the consumer or the producer a UI thread? Or a normal background thread?

Comment: If the performance demands are not strict, or the consumer thread is running  a GUI framework, AND THERE WILL ONLY EVER BE ONE CONSUMER, you can use a Windows message queue, PostMessage() and WaitForSingleObject().

Comment: Also, if you go with a CS-protected std::queue, (no, it's not inherently thread-safe, hence the CS), don't use an Event as a semahore - use a semaphore as a semaphore.

Comment: the producer and consumer thread will be background one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not well versed in the MFC synchronization tools, but what you want to do is definitely possible.

EDIT: Based on what people are saying in the comments, it looks like `CCriticalSection` is a better choice than `CMutex` in this case so I've updated my answer.

For signaling between threads, using semaphores would be a good choice. Wikipedia has a [nice example of pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_semaphores) using semaphores for the producer-consumer / bounded-buffer problem. Note that you will need two semaphores, one to count how many items are in the queue and how many slots the queue has left. Note that **with more than two threads, you also need a mutex-type or critical section synchronization mechanism** in addition to the semaphores (see the wiki link, second code example). This may seem counter-intuitive, but keep in mind the fact that the producer and the consumer are waiting on two different queue conditions before they act.

Based on what I've read, a good option is to make your own wrapper class with a [`CCriticalSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5zew56b.aspx) member, then when you want to lock the resource (like you would within one of your wrapper class' get/set member function) you call `CCriticalSection`'s `Lock()` method ([shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4956560/3602796)). When you're done with the shared resource, remember to call `Unlock()` on the `CCriticalSection`.

[Adapted From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd4179k7.aspx):

```
#include <queue>
class SharedQueue
{
   static std::queue<int> _qShared; //shared resource
   static CCriticalSection _critSect;
public:
   SharedQueue(void) {}
   ~SharedQueue(void) {}
   void push(int); //locks, modifies, and unlocks shared resource
};

//Declaration of static members and push_back
std::queue<int> SharedQueue::_qShared;
CCriticalSection SharedQueue::_critSect;

void SharedQueue::push(int item)
{
   _critSect.Lock();
   _qShared.push(item);
   _critSect.Unlock();
}
```

As pointed out in the comments and [in the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5zew56b.aspx), `CCriticalSection` is useful when access to your shared resource does not cross process boundaries. It is also more performant in this case than `CMutex`.

You need to wrap the `std::queue`, since it **is not thread safe**. Assume any container in the STL is not thread safe unless the documentation specifically mentions that it is.

Comment: Because it is in the same process, CCriticalSection is faster easier and uses less system resources.

Comment: ^^ what @xMRi says.  Within a process, use a CS.

Comment: thanks will...can u pls suggest what will the good signalling mechanism between 2 threads ...is it using Events or Condition variables or Semaphore. Condition variables are not supported on Win XP..

Comment: You can use a semaphore to reflect/signal the queue count.  That is a classic use for a semaphore.  Do not misuse an Event as a pseudo-semaphore.  An Event is not a semaphore.